# wordpress text area issue (only affect mobile)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, mobile

i have a padding problem that only affect mobiles.

[image]

the reason for this issue is some how known, but how to fix the the issue without affecting the computers preview.

here is the suspect

```
    .entry-content,
.entry-summary {
    margin-top: 20px;
    max-width:1000px;
    width: 100%;
    float: none; /* i don't know if this affect any thing */
    **float: none!important;** 
    **padding-left:150px !important;**    
               }
```

here a preview from the desktop so you can understand the reason behind the padding.

[image]

it looks like that padding in a general setting or so.
so what can be done to the solve the problem? 
re-allocate the padding line to more specific function ?
or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you identified the problem yourself. The padding is applied in the mobile page.

A fix would be to use a media query to find out if the user is viewing on a desktop. If he is, add the padding to the element.

first remove the padding from the main styling of the element

```
.entry-content,
  .entry-summary {
    margin-top: 20px;
    max-width:1000px;
    width: 100%;
    float: none; /* i don't know if this affect any thing */
    **float: none!important;**   
  }
```

and add something like this to your stylesheet

```
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
  .entry-content, .entry-summary {
    padding-left: 150px;
}
```

What this does is only applying the `padding-left` if the screen's width is larger than 1224 pixels (so a desktop, basically).

A better solution though, would be to change the elements so the left-padding is not needed to position the text right. But this is an HTML issue and I don't have enough information to help you with this.

Comment: great,so every thing inside this style.css is html ?

Comment: i have all of those :O

Comment: here is the code for all of them 
https://jsfiddle.net/Leq7yLzo/#&togetherjs=MArvf1vtkf

Comment: inside the style.css you add styling to the html elements defined in the other files. The html is in the .php or .html files. If you already have the media query's, I would suggest to do what I said in the answer. You can also add `padding-left: 0px;` to the media query's that shouldn't have the padding. EDIT: you'll need the `.entry-content, .entry-summary` wrapped around it like I did in my answer to select the correct element.

Comment: could you take a look at the photo from google drive ?

Comment: i have 10 media query's

Comment: some of them without .entry-content

Comment: there code will be on jsfiddle link i have sent you. did you check or i should use links you know about ?

Comment: Yes, I haven't worked with media query's too much but I think you can add the code in my answer to the first media query that should have the padding (ex: adding it to the 1032 should also add it to the 1176 and above, but I'm not too sure about this). remove the padding from the .entry-content in the css outside the media query's, and add the padding to the .entry-content inside a query. If there isn't a .entry-content you can savily define it.

Comment: you do understand me very well :), is it safe to add 
.entry-content,
.entry-summary { } under all media screen

Comment: nice example, but what is the need for the text class ?

Comment: It was just an example class, don't pay too much attention to the names I gave. You can add the `.entry-content, .entry-summary { }` to all media query's that need to edit it. Just notice the `min-width`, 1500 pixels still falls under the `min-width` of 1024, so if, for example, 1024 is the first screen size that should have the padding, only adding it to that query should do the trick.

Comment: but why i only have 1032 not 1024

Comment: have you ever seen 1032 screen ? :D

Comment: Well, I just came up with that number. You can use whatever size you want for the query's. I would suggest to just leave the numbers as is to not mess up the rest of your layout and mess around with adding it to the query's until your problem is fixed. There probably is a query where the left sidebar shown in your second screenshot (desktop view) is moved someplace else (or hidden). Adding it to the next query is the most logical place, since that is the first size with the sidebar on the left.

Comment: The reason why it's 1032 might be that at 1032 it works fine, but at 1031 the layout breaks. It's not really the device's screen width, but the browser's width. You can test the different effects at different sizes by resizing your browser slowly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122144/discussion-between-tijmenh-and-abdo-refky).

Comment: any way i am lucky that i was adjusting the max 600 not mix 600. thanks god my mobile has 600 px :). now i go edit the min 600